# How to caseless grep listing names of files containing ALL of several strings and NONE of another several strings

Tags: performance, search, grep

Frequently I want to generate a list of files having
the stated condition.

Suppose I want to find all files with a copyright and a main but
without using fcntl or a namespace.

Here is a clumsy approach:

```
fgrep -i -r -l copyright *|xargs fgrep -i -l main|xargs fgrep -i -l -v fcntl|xargs fgrep -i -l namespace
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the same result with a more sophisticated approach using standard utilities?

For fun, I have begun to write my own C++17 program to achieve a speedy result but I would love to find my own work unnecessary.  Here is my GitHub repository with that code:

https://github.com/jlettvin/Greased-Grep

Comment: I don't think `grep -lv 'pattern'` does what you want it to do. You want "file that doesn't contain `pattern`", but it's "file that contains a line that doesn't match `pattern`", which is typically every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With (GNU) grep, I would do this as follows:

```
grep -Flir 'main' . \
    | xargs grep -Fli 'copyright' \
    | xargs grep -FLi -e 'fcntl' -e 'namespace'
```

This is quite similar to what you had. To get files *not* containing a pattern, I use the `-L` option (you tried `-lv` – that returns the files that contain at least one line that doesn't match, i.e., typically all files).

For the last step, excluding files that don't match, I can do with just one grep invocation and multiple patterns specified with `-e`.

To make this more robust and allow for *any* characters in filenames, you can require that grep separates filenames with a NUL byte (`-Z`) and xargs expecting that (`-0`):

```
grep -FlirZ 'main' . \
    | xargs -0 grep -FliZ 'copyright' \
    | xargs -0 grep -FLi -e 'fcntl' -e 'namespace'
```